# Call a javascript function of base template from another template in django

Tags: javascript, html, django

in my base.html template, I write a function. Can I call it from another template?

I tried like this. It doesn't work.

base.html:

```
<!-- ...code... -->
<script>
        function registration(){
            if(document.getElementById("registration").className==='hide'){
                document.getElementById("registration").className='show'
            }else{
                document.getElementById("registration").className='hide'
            }
        }
</script>
```

another template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body %}
<script>
    //if i re write the function here, it works
    registration()
</script>

{% endblock body %}
```

Comment: Does `{% block body %}{% endblock %}` come before or after the `<script></script>` where `function registration()` is defined in base.html?

Comment: i write {% block body %}{% endblock %} before the <script></script> tag

Comment: Okay so the issue here is that `<script>` tags are evaluated *in order*. So you're trying to call the function before it's actually defined. You could create another block that sits *below* your other `<script>` tags e.g. `{% block extra %}` where you can insert additional `<script>` tags from other templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this in your `base.html`

```
<html>
<head>
<!---Here all the CSS links --->

{% block css %}
{% endblock css %}

<head>

<body>
{% block body %}
{% endblock body %}
</body>

{% block script %}
 //write your script here
{% endblock script %}
</html>
```

in other template you have to just do like this
for example `about.html`

```
{% block body %}
{% endblock body %}
```